# Is it possible to override a method of a generic class in Java?

Tags: java, c++, generics, inheritance, overriding

I know that in C++ there is no such thing as a virtual templates function. This is because we need to know the entries to the VTBL at compile time and each template type is compiled separately.

In Java however I understand that the generic type is compiled only once which can enable overriding methods of a generic class. Is this true?

If so, Does this design choice makes?

Comment: It's not called a template in java

Comment: They're called Generics

Comment: Do you mean, "Does this design choice make sense?"?

Comment: @aaronman - You're right. My bad :)

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have template classes. Instead, it has Generics, which are regular Java classes that have additional type information at compile-time that allows the compiler to perform type-safety checks. Once those checks are done, the information about the generic types is "erased", and the compiled class looks like any other class.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm aware of the type erasure and how it works. 
I'm asking if methods of a generic class can be overriden in a subclass ( and if it makes sense to even consider such a scenario ).

Comment: @Shookie There *is* no such thing as a template class, just regular classes that happen to have generic information at compile-time. Those methods can be overridden just like any other methods (i.e., as long as they're visible and not `final`). Take a look at `AbstractList<E>` for an example.

Comment: @Shookie There are lots of examples of this in the JDK. I suggest you look at the List and Map hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Any non final, non private, non static method can be overridden in a sub-class, whether it is generic or not.  This work because the type is actually a *reference* in every case.  When you change the type, you are just changing the type of the reference.

BTW All non-static methods are "virtual" in Java.